# Select multiple items from drop down (without repetition) and sum their values from a lookup

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

In sheet **`Input Variable`**, I have a cell **`F3`** containing *[multiple items selected from a drop down (without repetition)](https://trumpexcel.com/select-multiple-items-drop-down-list-excel/) and separated with comma.*

[image: drop down]

Their *lookup values* are in another sheet **`Ref Data`** as shown below:

[image: ref data]

I would like to get their sum in cell **`G3`**.

```
=VLOOKUP(F3,'Ref Data'!B:C,2,FALSE)
```

So far I am getting value for only one item.

For example:

[image: one item]

But when I select another item from the drop down, I am getting **`#N/A`** value

For example:

For items **`Delivery, Pilot`**, value should have been **`1500`** *(1000 + 500)*

[image: multiple item]

***How may I resolve this issue ?***

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(FIND(B2:B5,F3))),C2:C5)
```

A better explanation than I could come up with for how it works can be found [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-keywords-cell-contains)

Answer (score 0):

If the list contains elements which completely embed other elements such as "All Extras" has "All" in it and "copilot" completely embeds "pilot" (all lowercase for illustration purposes as `FIND` is case sensitive so "Pilot" is not in "Copilot"), use this additional bracketing so there are no erroneous charges.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(FIND(", "&B2:B5&",",", "&(F3)&","))),C2:C5)
```

Adding the commas to the selection "Delivery, Pilot" makes it ", Delivery, Pilot,".
Adding the commas to the array B2:B5 becomes {", Pilot,";", Delivery,"...}. For each of these array items (with their commas), `Find` returns `TRUE` when the element is in the selection and `FALSE` if the complete array element is not found in the selection. If there are commas in the service description, then use a different separator (such as pipe `|`) in the selection box value and use the same separator to bracket within this formula. The `--` double negation turns the `FIND` resultant boolean array into ones (true=found) and zeros (false=not found). The `SUMPRODUCT` multiplies this resultant array of ones and zeros by the row value of the corresponding Cost array C2:C5 and all of these products are summed.